# Python DELETE character (Unicode 7F) does not seem to do anything. Shouldn't it delete the succeeding character, or am I doing it wrong?

Tags: python, unicode, unicode-string, python-unicode, unicode-escapes

I went into my Python shell and tested this out, here are the results:

```
>>> print u"hi\u007F there"
hi there
```

According to my understanding of this character, it should have not shown the space in that string. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operation of the `DELETE` character (ASCII 7F) depends on the terminal; because it is being printed *before* the next character, it often does nothing at all. Historically, the [meaning of the 7F unicode codepoint has been unclear](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delete_character).

The `BACKSPACE` code, 08, operates on the *previous* character. As the terminal has already printed that, works correctly:

```
>>> print u"hi \u0008there"
hithere
```

Perhaps you can use that instead?

Comment: I am well aware of backspace (you don't need to use unicode for that, by the way, you can just use `\b`).

Comment: @Maxwell: just following your style. :-) For codepoints below FF you can use `\x..` escapes too: `\x08`.

Comment: Ah, I hope I didn't come off as unappreciative.